# Creating a fixed position element from arbitrary position on scroll

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed header, and want to add an additional fixed element below the header, when someone scrolls down to that element. I have managed to get pretty close to it, except when I am scrolling the new fixed element is jumping around a bit, and I can't work out why.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    height2 = $('#product_nav_cont').offset().top;
    scroll2 = $(this).scrollTop();
    header2 = $('#scroll_header_cont').outerHeight();
    pos2 = height2-header2

    if(scroll2 > pos2) {
        $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'fixed','top':header2,'width':'100%'});
    } else {
        $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'static','top':'0'});
    }
});
```

I think it may have something to do with the variable "height2", perhaps this position is changing on scroll due to the element being fixed when scrolling down the page, but I couldnt figure it out, if that is even the issue. Any ideas very much appreciated.

You can view the issue at, http://jsfiddle.net/LbpkLko8/1/

Comment: Please create a fiddle to show your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you create a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LbpkLko8/1/

Comment: You'd better use the **StackOverflow code snippet** instead of third-party website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put variables *header2* and *height2* outside the scroll function. Here is your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbpkLko8/3/) and the new code:

```
header2 = $('#scroll_header_cont').outerHeight();
height2 = $('#product_nav_cont').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll2 = $(this).scrollTop();
    pos2 = height2-header2

    if(scroll2 > pos2) {
        $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'fixed','top':header2,'width':'100%'});
    } else {
        $('#product_nav_cont').css({'position':'static','top':'0'});
    }
});
```